# Who has installed my android app via app invitation?

Tags: android

I would like to know who has installed my app via others invitation.

What I mean is that let's say I installed the app and send some URL to my friend to download this app also.

In google developer console or firebase console I would like to know which user has directly installed the app and who has by invitation.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is "attribution" - i.e., "to what do I *attribute* (credit) this installation?"

I don't have an exact answer for you, but search for "Android App Attribution" should get you going.
Here's a few links to get you started:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3389142?hl=en

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/understanding-attribution-in-firebase.html

Hope that helps!